# use NavigationDrawer in API 8

Tags: android, android-support-library, navigation-drawer

in offical documentation wrote min SDK for Navigation Drawer 11.
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

How can I use `NavigationDrawer` in support library in API 8(android 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android-suport library and `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>` 
as widget in your XML files. Here is a good tutorial [recursiverobot tutorial](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android)